# Apply additional parameters syntax

Tags: r, apply, zoo, rollapply

Let's say I have a data frame with columns of data, and I want to calculate the one-sided moving average of each column. Why does this work

```
my.rollapply <- function(x){

    return(rollapply(x,moving.avg,FUN= mean, fill = NA,align = 'right', na.rm = TRUE))

}

averageData <- apply(averageData, 2, my.rollapply)
```

but

```
averageData <- apply(averageData, 2, rollapply, width = moving.avg, FUN = mean, fill = NA, align = 'right', na.rm = TRUE)
```

gives me an error of

```
Error in mean.default(newX[, i], ...) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

Is this because mean itself requires additional parameters? How would I be able to pass in all the parameters to rollapply inside of apply then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation:

```
averageData <- apply(averageData, 2, rollapply, width = moving.avg,
                     FUN = mean, fill = NA, align = 'right', na.rm = TRUE)
```

This won't work (and isn't a good idea) for a couple reasons (maybe more):

1. `FUN` is a formal argument to both `apply` and `rollapply`.
2. `...` are are passed to `rollapply` *and* passed to `mean`.

Since `FUN` is a formal argument to `apply`, it's matched to the `apply` call and not passed via `...` to the `rollapply` call. So your `apply` call is interpreted as:

```
apply(X=averageData, MARGIN=2, FUN=mean, rollapply, width=moving.avg,
      fill=NA, align='right', na.rm=TRUE)
```

Which means the `mean` call inside the `apply` loop is:

```
mean(tmp[,i], ...)
# which is equivalent to
mean(tmp[,i], rollapply, width=moving.avg, fill=NA, align='right', na.rm=TRUE)
```

Which fails because the `trim` argument is `rollapply`, which is a function, not a numeric vector of length 1.

## Solution:

Regardless, the easy way to solve this problem is to use the `by.column` argument of `rollapply`:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.zoo(sample_matrix)
y <- rollmeanr(x, k=moving.avg, fill=NA, na.rm=TRUE, by.column=TRUE)
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm defining the function beforehand for now, but I just wanted to better understand the structure of apply's ...
Thanks for clearing it up!